# .htaccess wordpress redirect url to specific file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi i see all thread here but codes not work for my problem.
I have a custom page landing.php (in root of wp site) and this is landing page with one link only (static page)

I want to `site.com/landing.php` redirect just to `site.com/landing/` , but landing.php redirect to /landing

I try with this code:
                   `RewriteRule ^landing/?$ landing.php [L]`

But in this case i can open /landing/ and /landing.php, i want landing.php redirect to /landing/

Thanks

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you actually want... Please describe _exactly_ what URL will get entered in a browser and where it should get rewritten or redirected to (note: those are two separate things).

Comment: mysite.com/landing.php i want to redirect in mysite.com/landing/

Comment: Then the question is: what will happen if you request `https://example.com/landing/`...

Comment: So, with your .htaccess, browsing to `mysite.com/landing/` works correctly, right? And browsing to `mysite.com/landing.php` also displays - it displays exactly the same thing as the redirect from `mysite.com/landing/`, true?  So ... what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you actually want...

But this is the answer to what you specifically asked in the comment to your question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?landing\.php$ /landing/ [R=301]
```

That rule will work likewise in the real http server's host configuration and in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style files).

A remark however: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

However considering what is *typically* done for simple web projects I *guess* this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?landing\.php$ /landing/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?landing/?$ /landing.php [END]
```

In case you experience an internal server error using above rules (http status 500) then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You should try to upgrade, in case that is not possible have a try using the `L` flag instead of the `END` flag. It might work just fine depending on your setup.